# How to make a columns contents display in a tool-tip when hovering over? HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html-table

I'm using a HTML table to display my content on my webpage. I'm having trouble on figuring out how to make a columns contents display when it is hovered over. For example if I hovered over a cell on the table (which has the tool-tip enabled), the contents of that cell should appear in a tool-tip.

I am currently using JavaScript & J Query to build the table, I have included static data to display in the table:

```
var AuditLog = [
    { UserID: "DJoe1", Action: "loggedIn", Date: "17 July 2014 11:02", AppID:"MyRoster", DeviceID: "-", Notes: "None" },
    { UserID: "DJoe2", Action: "loggedIn", Date: "17 July 2014 10:49", AppID: "Train Dispatch", DeviceID: "-", Notes: "None" },
    { UserID: "DJoe3", Action: "loggedIn", Date: "17 July 2014 10:29", AppID: "MyRoster", DeviceID: "-", Notes: "None" },
    { UserID: "LJenkins2", Action: "loggedIn", Date: "17 July 2014 10:15", AppID: "Train Dispatch", DeviceID: "-", Notes: "None" },
    { UserID: "LJenkins1", Action: "loggedIn", Date: "17 July 2014 10:11", AppID: "Train Dispatch", DeviceID: "-", Notes: "None" }
    ];
```

The column which needs the tool-tip is the Notes column. Table Structure:

```
                 var AuditHTML = "<table class='tablesorter full_width_table info_table_style ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive' id='auditTable'>" +
                    "<thead >" +
                       "<tr class='ui-bar-b schedule_row '>" +
                         "<th>User ID</th>" +
                         "<th>Action</th>" +
                         "<th>Date</th>" +
                         "<th>App ID</th>" +
                         "<th>Device ID</th>" +
                         "<th>Notes</th>" +
                       "</tr>" +
                     "</thead>" +
                     "<tbody>";

    for (s = 0; s < AuditLog.length; s++) {

        AuditHTML += "<tr class='schedule_row display' id='auditTr_" + s + "'>" +

          "<td> " + AuditLog[s].UserID + "</td>" +
                  "<td> " + AuditLog[s].Action + "</td>" +
                  "<td> " + AuditLog[s].Date + "</td>" +
                  "<td> " + AuditLog[s].AppID + "</td>" +
                  "<td> " + AuditLog[s].DeviceID + "</td>" +
                  "<td> " + AuditLog[s].Notes + "</td>";

        AuditHTML += "</tr>";
    }

    AuditHTML += "</tbody></table>";

$("#auditContent").html(AuditHTML);
```

I have used a div to display the table on the page:

```
  <div id="auditContent">
        </div>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: there is no code shown relating to any tooltip. WHat is your sepcific issue?

Comment: I don't know how I would go about doing it. Is it possible?

Comment: certainly it's possible. There are many many tooltip plugins. Do some searching on web. This is not a `how to` site. It is more for specific code related problems. After you find something and have problems with implementation you can get help then

Comment: I have done a lot of research on the web and have tried to implement them. If you could recommend me one of these many many tool-tip plugins which may help with my query, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry...that's up to you and questions asking for recommendations are against site policy

Comment: http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/  .This is good,Have a look

Comment: Tell me if it's right: you want the Notes column hidden by default. Then you want to show the cell of that Notes column that correspond to the row you hover over in your table ?

Comment: Not quite. The notes column will only display 50 characters maximum, to see the whole of the note the user should hover over the cell. All of the note will then display in the tool-tip. - This is just for the notes column

Comment: Thanks for the link also dileep, i'll take a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've done to try to solve your problem.
First I've changed a bit this javascript variable to add more length to the first two notes :

```
var AuditLog = [
{ UserID: "DJoe1", Action: "loggedIn", Date: "17 July 2014 11:02", AppID:"MyRoster", DeviceID: "-", Notes: "Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text " },
{ UserID: "DJoe2", Action: "loggedIn", Date: "17 July 2014 10:49", AppID: "Train Dispatch", DeviceID: "-", Notes: "Long content Long content Long content Long content Long content Long content Long content Long content Long content Long content Long content Long content Long content Long content Long content " },
{ UserID: "DJoe3", Action: "loggedIn", Date: "17 July 2014 10:29", AppID: "MyRoster", DeviceID: "-", Notes: "None" },
{ UserID: "LJenkins2", Action: "loggedIn", Date: "17 July 2014 10:15", AppID: "Train Dispatch", DeviceID: "-", Notes: "None" },
{ UserID: "LJenkins1", Action: "loggedIn", Date: "17 July 2014 10:11", AppID: "Train Dispatch", DeviceID: "-", Notes: "None" }
];
```

In the rest of your Javascript code, I just added a class `note` like that :

```
"<td class='note'> " + AuditLog[s].Notes + "</td>";
```

I also used a bit of CSS :

```
td, th{
    border:solid gray 1px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}

table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.note{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden; 
    width:200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

And finally I added a jquery event to animate the hovering of an element :

```
$('.note').hover(
            function(event){
                $(event.target).css({
                        "white-space":"normal",
                        "text-overflow":"clip",                     
                        "background-color":"#eeeeee",
                        "max-width":"500px",
                        "position":"absolute"
                    });
            }, function(event){
                $(event.target).css({
                        "white-space":"nowrap",
                        "text-overflow":"ellipsis",                     
                        "background-color":"transparent",
                        "max-width":"200px",
                        "position":"static"
                    });
            }
);
```

It's a basic solution, but I think you can work with that to improve it

Answer (score 0):

do you want to display content while doing mouse over on column or in tooltip?

if you want to display content on mouser over on column then you can add onmouseover event to cell/row of HTML table and hide/display content based on requirement.

or if you want to show as tooltip

add span tag and show span tag on mouser over.

```
<span onMouseOver="toolTip('simple Tooltip Text here')" onMouseOut="toolTip()"
class="Text">Simple Tooltip</span>
```

[check this link to see example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20515/A-Simple-Tooltip-With-Images-And-Text)

Comment: The tool-tip should display the content in the table cell that the user is hovering over. Hope that made sense :)

Comment: Thanks :) Please see my updated original answer. I hope that helps you :)